# jfeinstein10's SlidingMenu - how to detect slide event

Tags: android, slidingmenu

I am using the SlidingMenu as a `SlidingFragmentActivity`. It is a great library and relatively easy to use, but i have a small problem. I want to detect when users slide from the ContentView back to the BehindContentView.

Comment: This should not be closed.  I had the same question.  I can get the menu being shown from onOptionsItemSelected, but not from the sliding of the screen by the user.  The answer below is the correct answer for this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found [this listener](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu/blob/master/library/src/com/slidingmenu/lib/SlidingMenu.java#L84-L90) interface going through the source code. You can use it like this:

```
mySlidingMenu.setOnOpenListener(new OnOpenListener() {
        @override
        public void onOpen() {
            // Do something
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Don't know how i missed that.